sdkmager caused Warning: Errors during XML parse:
I followed this instroctions to install Android SDK without Android Studio on ARM64 Chromebook.Unfortunately, I ran into the following errors:
$ sdkmanager --update
Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                               
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.             
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
No updates available
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...             

$ sdkmanager --install emulator
Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                               
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.             
Warning: Failed to find package 'emulator'                                      $                     ] 10% Computing updates...              

$ ping -c 5 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.167.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from syd09s17-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=37.8 ms
64 bytes from syd09s17-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=35.6 ms
64 bytes from syd09s17-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.110): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=33.7 ms
64 bytes from syd09s17-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.110): icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=38.2 ms
64 bytes from syd09s17-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.110): icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=41.1 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.683/37.261/41.072/2.500 ms


Try sdkmanager --install "emulator"
For whatever reason, it seems to want the package name surrounded in double-quotes.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
